# ¿como sumar 2 números ingresados a una cadena de texto que están separados por un espacio? JAVA

Tags: java, string

Tengo una cadena de texto que vendría siendo la siguiente:

```
String cadena="1 2";
```

este como resultado me debe dar "3" teniendo en cuenta el espacio que hay entre ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar algo sencillo como esto:

```
  String cadena="1 2";
  String[] arr = cadena.split(" ");
  System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(arr[0]) + Integer.valueOf(arr[1]));
```

Comment: muchas gracias!